# [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: getaddrinfo failed: No such host in known

Tags: php, xml

I created a page that loads external XML into an HTML page from a wordpress site. It works on my MAMP testing locally. When I install it on my server for production I get an error for the php script:

DOMDocument::load(http://blog.website.com/feed/): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

The script for the code is here where all the info gets pulled.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load("http://blog.website.com/feed/");
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array (
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'author' => $node->getElementsByTagName('creator')->item(0)->nodeValue,
);
```

Checked the php.ini and fopen is enabled, so I'm not particularly sure why I'm having the issue.

Comment: Have you access to a terminal on that machine?

Comment: Can you ping `blog.website.com`? (or what it stands for)

Comment: No it appears I can't ping the address.

Comment: Also pinged the ip address itself and the requests timed out

Comment: you'll have to change the DNS or network settings of your server